# ERROR: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm getting this weird error.

```
    Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [
```

I don't know why this error occurs.

Could anyone please tell me why this error occurs and how to solve it?

```
sortedArray.push({filteredKeys[i]:_analyzedDataSet[filteredKeys[i]]});
```

This error occurs on this line above.

```
console.log("filteredKeys[i]:%s", filteredKeys[i]);
```

However, this line above works fine.

```
console.log("_analyzedDataSet[filteredKeys[i]]:%s", _analyzedDataSet[filteredKeys[i]]);
```

Also, this line above works fine.

```
var filteredKeys = [];

filteredKeys = sortThis(_analyzedDataSet);

var sortedArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < filteredKeys.length; i++){

    //This doesn't cause an error.
    console.log("filteredKeys[i]:%s", filteredKeys[i]);

    //This doesn't cause an error as well.
    console.log("_analyzedDataSet[filteredKeys[i]]:%s", _analyzedDataSet[filteredKeys[i]]);

    //But, this cause an error!!
    sortedArray.push({filteredKeys[i]:_analyzedDataSet[filteredKeys[i]]});
}
```

Comment: what are you trying to do with that colon in there?

Comment: the colon is the divider for key & value.{"key":"value}

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object "Parameters

nameValuePair1, nameValuePair2, ... nameValuePairN
Pairs of names **(strings)** and values (any value) where the name is separated from the value by a colon."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't add dynamic keys to an object when using an object literal notation. Create the object first and add the key using array notation

```
var newObj = {};
newObj[filteredKeys[i]] = _analyzedDataSet[filteredKeys[i]];
sortedArray.push(newObj);
```

Comment: OK! Thanks! I'm going to try it now :)

Comment: >can't add dynamic keys to an object when using an object literal notation

I didn't know that.

Comment: Yeah, it isn't going to evaluate the key in the object literal for the return value and assign that to the key. It was trying to add a key literally called 'filteredKeys[i]' to the object, but didn't like the square bracket in the identifier.